# SQL Logic - Record field Changed but no Changes since

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I have a situation where I need to locate all member records that changed from a status of active to a status of freeze in a period of time. The issue is, a member can change statuses multiple times. For example, a member can change their status from active to freeze on June 1. Then back to active on September 1 and then back to freeze for December 1. I am trying to run a query to identify all of the members who froze from June 1 and are still frozen but that have not changes their status in between.

The code I have identifies all of the people, but does not eliminate people who changes multiple times.

The code I have so far is:

```
SELECT 
    MEMBERUDFS.memid, MEMBERUDFS.udfid, MEMBERUDFS.udfvalue,  
    MEMBERUDFSETUPS.udflabel, 
    MEMBERS.lname, MEMBERS.fname, MEMBERTYPES.description, 
    SITES.sitename, MEMBERS.status, 
    MEMBERCHANGES.datechange, MEMBERCHANGES.newvalue, 
    MEMBERCHANGES.columnname
FROM 
    MEMBERUDFS 
INNER JOIN 
    MEMBERUDFSETUPS ON MEMBERUDFS.udfid = MEMBERUDFSETUPS.udfid 
INNER JOIN 
    MEMBERS ON MEMBERUDFS.memid = MEMBERS.memid 
INNER JOIN 
    MEMBERTYPES ON MEMBERS.mtypeid = MEMBERTYPES.mtypeid 
INNER JOIN 
    SITES ON MEMBERS.siteid = SITES.siteid 
INNER JOIN 
    MEMBERCHANGES ON MEMBERS.memid = MEMBERCHANGES.memid
WHERE 
    (MEMBERUDFSETUPS.udflabel = 'Freeze Reason') 
    AND (MEMBERUDFS.udfvalue = 'Medical') 
    AND (MEMBERS.status = 'F') 
    AND (MEMBERS.siteid = '777') 
    AND (MEMBERCHANGES.columnname = 'status') 
    AND (MEMBERCHANGES.newvalue = 'F') 
    AND (MEMBERCHANGES.datechange BETWEEN '2015-07-01' AND '2015-12-31')
```

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: Thank you. I updated the tag. SQL Server with Report Services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
AND NOT EXISTS (
SELECT *
FROM
MEMBERCHANGES c2
WHERE
c2.memid = MEMBERCHANGES.memid AND
c2.datechange > MEMBERCHANGES.datechange
);
```